# SQL pivot with multiple column data in one with comma separation

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-pivot

SQL Query Table:

```
Date        Production LineName  Buyer Style
2021-04-30  100          A       Lev    1a
2021-04-30  200          B       Kont   2d
2021-04-30  300          C       ABB    4l
2021-04-30  400          A       Lev    1a
2021-04-29  600          A       BDA    3z
```

Output need like:

```
LineName  2021-04-29  2021-04-30
A         600,BDA,3Z  500,Lev,1a
B         NULL        200,Kont,2d
C         NULL        300,ABB,4l
```

I started coding and stuck at

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)
    ,@Dates VARCHAR(4000)

SET @Dates = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + Cast([Date] As Varchar)
            FROM Table_17M
            ORDER BY '],[' + Cast([Date] As Varchar)
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @query = ';With PivotData
As
(
    Select 
        LineName, -- grouping element
        [Date], -- spreading element
        PlanProduction-- aggregating element
    From Table_17M
)
Select *
From PivotData
Pivot (Sum(PlanProduction) For [Date] In (' + @Dates + ')) As P;'

EXEC (@query);
```

Any idea please share. It will very much helpful. Thanks.

Comment: So what does @query actually contain, and what does running it give?

Comment: I just find the day wise production by above query. Beside production i need style & Buyer information also with comma separation

Comment: Which sql server version you are using?

Comment: Server Management Studio 18

Comment: That's the version of SSMS, not SQL Server @RafiqulIslamParvez . What version of SQL Server are you using? Also note that syntax like `'[' +SomeValue+']'` is *not* injection safe. Use `QUOTENAME` to safely injext dynamic objects. Finally (a pet peeve) the semicolon (`;`) is a statement **terminator**; it goes at the end of *all* your statements not the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.

Comment: Provided there exist different `Buyer + Style` rows for a `Date +       LineName` value what kind of aggregation is requiered?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer 2017 or later version then use string_agg() instead of suff(). It's easier to implement and much faster.

```
select @cols=  string_agg(quotename([date]),',') from (select distinct [date] from Table_17M)t
```

DB-Fiddle

```
 create table Table_17M(Date Date,Production int, LineName varchar(50), Buyer varchar(50), Style varchar(50));
 insert into Table_17M values('2021-04-30',  100,          'A',       'Lev',    '1a');
 insert into Table_17M values('2021-04-30',  200,          'B',       'Kont',   '2d');
 insert into Table_17M values('2021-04-30',  300,          'C',       'ABB' ,   '4l');
 insert into Table_17M values('2021-04-30',  400,          'A',       'Lev' ,   '1a');
 insert into Table_17M values('2021-04-29',  600,          'A',       'BDA' ,   '3z');
```

Query:

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
     
 SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + quotename([date])
             FROM Table_17M
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
         ,1,1,'')
                
            
        
 set @query = 'select LineName , ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
             
             select LineName,[date],concat(sum(production),'','',max(buyer),'','',string_agg(Style,'','')) other_columns
             from Table_17M
             group by LineName,[date]
             ) x
             pivot 
             (
               max(other_columns)
               for [date] in (' + @cols + ')
 
             ) p 
             group by LineName , ' + @cols 
 
 execute( @query)
```

Output:

| LineName | 2021-04-29 | 2021-04-30 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 600,BDA,3z | 500,Lev,1a,1a |
| B | null | 200,Kont,2d |
| C | null | 300,ABB,4l |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d831a315c69c0708e6ea76d98f50cb12)*

Comment: Many Many Thanks brother Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur .I got my answer form ur answer.

Comment: You are most welcome brother. You were close. Your question deserves upvote. Nice to know that you got your answer. best wishes.

Comment: Dear   Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur,

Comment: Dear Sir Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur, A simple little more facility can u give me if possible. It is possible if i have one more style then show with comma separation. Like 500,Lev, 1a,1b, 1d. It will perfectly fit.

Comment: Sure. Which version of sql server you are using? is it 2019 or 2017 or something else?

Comment: @RafiqulIslamParvez I have revised my answer. If you are using sql server 2017 or later version you can use string_agg() if you are using older version then you need to use stuff() with xml path for() instead. Please let me know.

Comment: Alhamdulillah, Many thanks for your answer. I am using sql 2017. I try STRING_AGG (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),Style), CHAR(13)). It is working good. It Separated style with space but i need comma. I tired to use comma. If possible sir help me. Thanks

Comment: Please look into my revised answer. for comma you need to use string_agg(Style,',').

Comment: Many thanks Sir @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur, I got it. Thanks to save my many times. Alhamdulillah. If possible to help my simple project some time by u It will great help for my country BD Garments Industries. My project Garments MIS Software & planning. www.garmentsmis.com. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome. Definitely will look into it. Best wishes for your project.

Comment: Dear Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur brother,

Comment: Dear Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur brother, I need a little help on it. I am tried to add my header date format like 29 Mar 2021 Sun .... I use FORMAT(date,'dd-MMM-yyyy ddd'. But it is giving me error date converting issue. Can you pls help me.

Comment: Thanks Dear, Not need to try above question. I solved it by edit gridview header row.

Comment: @RafiqulIslamParvez Sorry didn't notice your comment since I was offline. It's great to know that the problem has been resolved. Best of luck.